# Tailwind CSS grid for responsive sizes?

Tags: tailwind-css

New to Tailwind CSS but know CSS, I want to create a responsive set of boxes using Tailwind CSS. I have this sample code but I want to make them 12 cols on small screens and then on medium make them all 6 cols. I took the mobile-first approach but I can't seem to get the medium size?! All I see on my machine is the 12 col and nothing else, why does the `md:` get ignored?

Here I can see it works: https://play.tailwindcss.com/EOdbWVnwgc I have version 3.3.3 of TailwindCSS (I am using the [standalone CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli) build without node.js).

Do I need to add some extra library to make it work on my local setup?

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">1</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">2</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">3</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">4</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">5</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider checking the file globs in the `content` array in the Tailwind configuration file, or the file globs in the `--content` argument cover the file that the code is in.

Comment: I checked the content array and all seems fine, everything renders as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided, and the tailwind play link, is not the same. You have written `grid-cols-12` here and `grid-cols-3` in the tailwind playground.
So in the code from playground sets up a grid that offers 3 columns and the sub elements all scale to a minimum of 6 columns now (on medium+ devices).

I hope this helps. [Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gGrvkawMkH)

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">1</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">2</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">3</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">4</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">5</div>
  <div class="col-span-12 md:col-span-6 bg-teal-400">6</div>
</div>
```